# Android 8 receive of stop receiving media buttons events

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-8.0-oreo

I have a service that listens to media buttons, but I only want to listen to those when my service is running since I have a button on the UI to start/stop the service.

How can I achieve the following two actions:

- On MyService start-up, start receiving media button events to com.myApp/MyService.
- On MyService end, stop receiving media button events in com.myApp/MyService.

The related logs are the following:

```
D MediaSessionService: Sending KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK, scanCode=226, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=13258317, downTime=13258317, deviceId=4, source=0x101 } to com.myApp/MyService (userId=0)
```

Note:

- I found out that I can start receiving media events after my app started to play audio. This is however not ideal, since I don't want to play audio in my app. (I am only using media events in order to trigger voice recognition)
- After I played audio, my service is apparently the default media receiver. This means that when a media button is pressed, my service get instantiated, does nothing, and get destroyed. This is not an idea behavior for the end user since my app ends up 'stealing' these events that could potentially be handled by something else.
- Overriding `OnStartCommand()` in my service does not help
- Calling SetMediaButtonReceiver on the MediaSession does not help either
- Using a BroadcastReceiver with the intent "android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" registered in the AudioManager does not work either

Relevant code (in C#, I am on Xamarin.Forms, but that should not have any impact on the way to achieve this)

```
public class MediaSessionCompatCallback : MediaSessionCompat.Callback
{
    public Func<Intent, bool> MediaButtonEvent { get; set; }
    public override bool OnMediaButtonEvent(Intent mediaButtonEvent) => MediaButtonEvent?.Invoke(mediaButtonEvent) ?? false;
}

[Service(Exported = true, Enabled = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { ServiceInterface })]
public class MediaBrowserService : MediaBrowserServiceCompat, AudioManager.IOnAudioFocusChangeListener
{
    private MediaSessionCompat mediaSession;
    private MediaSessionCompatCallback mediaSessionCallback;

    private void CreateMediaSessionCallback()
    {
        mediaSessionCallback = new MediaSessionCompatCallback()
        {
            MediaButtonEvent = OnMediaButtonEvent
        };
    }

    private void SetupMediaSession()
    {
        CreateMediaSessionCallback();

        var stateBuilder = new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder().SetActions(PlaybackStateCompat.ActionPlay | PlaybackStateCompat.ActionPlayPause);

        mediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(this, nameof(MediaBrowserService));
        mediaSession.SetFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FlagHandlesMediaButtons | MediaSessionCompat.FlagHandlesTransportControls);
        mediaSession.SetPlaybackState(stateBuilder.Build());
        mediaSession.SetCallback(mediaSessionCallback);
        mediaSession.Active = true;

        SessionToken = mediaSession.SessionToken;
    }

    private void BuildNotification() { [...] }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();

        SetupMediaSession();
        StartForeground(135, BuildNotification());
        ContextCompat.StartForegroundService(ApplicationContext, new Intent(ApplicationContext, Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(MediaBrowserService))));
    }

    public override void OnDestroy()
    {
        base.OnDestroy();

        if (mediaSession != null)
        {
            mediaSession.Active = false;
            mediaSession.SetCallback(null);
            mediaSession.Release();
            mediaSession.Dispose();
            mediaSession = null;
        }

        if (mediaSessionCallback != null)
        {
            mediaSessionCallback.Dispose();
            mediaSessionCallback = null;
        }

        StopForeground(true);
        StopSelf();
    }
}
```

Comment: Also note that using a BroadcastReceiver with the intent android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON registered in the AudioManager does not help either

Comment: Did you try to use the foreground service? It will push a notification. this service will not be closed if the application is running.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/foreground-services

Comment: Yes this is what these two lines are doing `StartForeground(135, BuildNotification()); ContextCompat.StartForegroundService(ApplicationContext, new Intent(ApplicationContext, Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(MediaBrowserService))));
`